# How to use Guids in C#?

Tags: c#, guid

This Code:

```
Something = new Guid()
```

is returning:

> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

all the time and I can't tell why? So, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# how to create a Guid value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344098/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-guid-value)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You should use [`Guid.NewGuid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)

Comment: @Ante: If you have the Guid class then you have the NewGuid method.

Answer (score 61):

Just a quick explanation for why you need to call NewGuid as opposed to using the default constructor... In .NET all structures (value types like int, decimal, Guid, DateTime, etc) must have a default parameterless constructor that initializes all of the fields to their default value. In the case of Guid, the bytes that make up the Guid are all zero. Rather than making a special case for Guid or making it a class, they use the NewGuid method to generate a new "random" Guid.

Answer (score 12):

It's in `System.Guid.`

To dynamically create a GUID in code:

```
Guid messageId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

To see its value:

```
string x = messageId.ToString();
```

Comment: Yes, it should be there (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid_members.aspx) but I can't use it. Why?

Comment: "I can't use it" - what happens when you try to use it? Type it out manually (perhaps there's an issue with your intellisense) and try to compile - do you get compilation errors?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "can't use it"? If you type Guid x = System.Guid.NewGuid() and compile, do you get an error? Or do you not like the value you're getting for x?

Comment: LOL yea that Guid algorithm sometimes needs a fresh reboot. Sigh.

Answer (score 4):

`something = new Guid()` equals `something = Guid.Empty`.

Use `Guid.NewGuid();` instead

Answer (score 3):

```
 Guid g1 = Guid.NewGuid();

 string s1;
 s1 = g1.ToString();
 Console.WriteLine("{0}",s1);
 Console.ReadKey();
```