# C# how to create a Guid value?

Tags: c#, guid

One field of our struct is `Guid` type. How to generate a valid value for it?

Comment: Onine you can use this https://devtoolsonline20190908040816.azurewebsites.net/DevTools/GuidGenerator

Answer (score 1115, accepted):

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: If you, like me, make the mistake of doing (new Guid().toString()) you will get 0000-00000-00000-00000. You need to do Guid.NewGuid().toString()

Comment: You might be interested in formatting Guid too https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Little correction, there is no function 'toString()' on Guid object, it is 'ToString()'

Answer (score 108):

There are two ways

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

or

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

both use the Guid class, the first creates a Guid Object, the second a Guid string.

Comment: @Justin, That's kind of one way to do it. `var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` just turns it in to a string.

Comment: @MichaelMeadows Yes that is correct, the first one creates a new Guid Object, the second creates a string.

Answer (score 106):

`Guid.NewGuid()` creates a new random guid.

Answer (score 61):

[Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) will create one

Answer (score 37):

To makes an "empty" all-0 guid like `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

```
var makeAllZeroGuID = new System.Guid();
```

or

```
var makeAllZeroGuID = System.Guid.Empty;
```

To makes an actual guid with a unique value, what you probably want.

```
var uniqueGuID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 36):

```
var guid = new Guid();
```

Hey, its a 'valid', although not very useful, Guid.

*(the guid is all zeros, if you don't know. Sometimes this is needed to indicate no guid, in cases where you don't want to use a nullable Guid)*

Comment: That does not create all zeros. It creates a valid Guid. Guid.Empty returns all zeros.

Comment: @FlavorScape before you try, I bet you 50 rep (via bounty) you are wrong.  Deal?

Comment: meh, i was thinking of Guid.NewGuid(). I really care to verify the new Guid()

Comment: I beat you by one with this solution: `var guid = new Guid(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, });`

Comment: What cases can you provide where one would use this over a nullable guid?

Comment: When you must pass a guid to code you don't own that doesn't accept a nullable guid.

Answer (score 33):

If you want to create a "desired" Guid you can do

```
var tempGuid = Guid.Parse("<guidValue>");
```

where `<guidValue>` would be something like `1A3B944E-3632-467B-A53A-206305310BAE`.

Answer (score 22):

```
System.Guid desiredGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: This seems to be the new way to do this, as of at least 2012. I don't seem to have Guid.NewGuid() available in 2015.

Comment: @DaveYarwood Guid has been under the System namespace for a very long time, and is what every one else is referring to in the other answers (it just happens to be that a new class already has the Using added in for the System Namespace in the normal template)

Answer (score 7):

There's also ShortGuid - A shorter and url friendly GUID class in C#. It's
 available as a [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSharpVitamins.ShortGuid/). More information [here](https://www.singular.co.nz/2007/12/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp/).

```
PM> Install-Package CSharpVitamins.ShortGuid
```

Usage:

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
ShortGuid sguid1 = guid; // implicitly cast the guid as a shortguid
Console.WriteLine(sguid1);
Console.WriteLine(sguid1.Guid);
```

This produces a new guid, uses that guid to create a ShortGuid, and displays the two equivalent values in the console. Results would be something along the lines of:

```
ShortGuid: FEx1sZbSD0ugmgMAF_RGHw 
Guid:      b1754c14-d296-4b0f-a09a-030017f4461f
```

Answer (score 4):

Using '

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

You need:

```
using System;
```

Which mainly used in any C# code.

If any issue, make sure **Guid** is not **overwritten**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this in the Reflection C#, you can get the guid from the property attribute as follows

```
var propertyAttributes= property.GetCustomAttributes();
foreach(var attribute in propertyAttributes)
{
  var myguid= Guid.Parse(attribute.Id.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy. The .Net framework provides an in-built function to create and parse GUIDS. This is available in the System namespace and the static Guid class.

To create a GUID just use the code below:

```
var newGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
```

To parse a GUID string as a GUID, use the code below:

```
var parsedGuid = System.Guid.Parse(guidString);
```

If you just want to create a new guide and just use it in your application, just use one of the [online GUID Generator](https://slickseotools.com/guid-generator) tools online to create yourself a new guid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ABP framework, it is recommended to use IGuidGenerator.Create() instead of Guid.NewGuid(). This is to ensure GUIDs are sequential, improving read/write times on the database.
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Guid-Generation#iguidgenerator