# Guid in c# returned zeroed

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, guid

I have a problem with Guid using c#, in my application, all field of type GUID were returned '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'.

How do I can to resolve the problem?

If need, I would put code.

Comment: All zeros is valid Guid - so not sure what your problem is. Clearly you know how to create one - search https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+create+guid immediately gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344098/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-guid-value. So please clarify what you have problem with so it can be answered.

Comment: That represents `Guid.Empty`. You haven't shown us your code but you've obviously not set the guid. You need to use `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use NewGuid method

```
Guid.NewGuid()
```

As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This is a convenient static method that you can call to get a new
>   Guid. The method wraps a call to the Windows CoCreateGuid function.
>   The returned Guid is guaranteed to not equal Guid.Empty.

Comment: This is exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344098/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-guid-value ... Not sure why you think it solves problem OP has in new way (and missing description of problem too).

Answer (score 4):

The default value of `Guid` is `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
As I consider you are using constuctor of Guid and you are getting a default value of Guid.

```
 var g = new Guid();
```

In this example `g` equals to the default value of `guid` and equals `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`.

In order to generate `guid`you should use `Guid.NewGuid`method.

```
var g = Guid.NewGuid();
```