# How to gen a sequential unique number by difference app type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've built a MVC web application and need to generate a unique sequential serial number by application type and year when users submit a form.

The serial number will be stored in the database table MyAppCodeSEQ and the column "AppCode" is a PK of MyAppCodeSEQ.

This is my code below:

```
public MyAppCodeSEQ GenNewAppCode(string appType)
{
    MyAppCodeSEQ model = null;
    try
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now;

        int maxSeq = _db.MyAppCodeSEQ.Where(x => x.AppType == appType && x.Year == today.Year).Select(x => x.SEQ).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();

        maxSeq = maxSeq + 1;
        var appCode = "XX" + appType + today.Year % 1000 + string.Format("{0:000000}", maxSeq);

        model = new MyAppCodeSEQ()
        {
            AppCode = appCode,
            AppType = appType,
            Year = today.Year,
            SEQ = maxSeq,                        
        };

        _db.MyAppCodeSEQ.Add(model);
        _db.SaveChanges();             
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {      
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        GenNewAppCode(appType);
    }

    return model;
}
```

The function will be recall while a duplicated key is inserted. however, the below error was occurred again and again.

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AppCodeSEQ'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MyAppCodeSEQ'. The duplicate key value is (XXYY18002193).
The statement has been terminated.
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
 System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
```

Is there any better solution to generate a serial number?

Comment: Let the database do it for you by using the primary key as part of the serial number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# how to create a Guid value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344098/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-guid-value)

Comment: Possibly store all the components of your serial number in their own columns, that way the auto incrementing `int` portion can be the primary key? You can have a `[NotMapped]` column that assembles the ref number for you to use in code.

Comment: Generating your own IDs is generally not necessary. Just let the database create it for you using an auto_increment field. Then it removes all problems relating to generating duplicates etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) NEVER have a primary key that is editable, let the database generate the primary key

b) The fields you are talking about is a "candidate" key and the purpose is usually for "sorting" into a default sequence or for guaranteeing uniqueness

c) A sequential key is pretty much a meaningless piece of data

That said, here's one possibility:

Alter your class (MyAppCodeSEQ) to include an Added field as DateTime.  Unique Index on AppCode, AppType, Year to prevent duplicates.  Index on AppCode, AppType, Year, Added to preserve sequence.